# How does the stamina store work on Flick Kick Football Legends?

Tags: football-legends

Before purchasing stamina on the stamina store I have some questions:

1. How long stamina reserves last (both "greater" and "maximum")?
2. Can I buy both?
3. When buying stamina refills it says "Regain some stamina". How much is "some"?

[image: Stamina]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably already figured it out but I had this doubt as well and did some testing in case anyone else wants to know.

**1. How long stamina reserves last (both "greater" and "maximum")?**

- Greater lasts for 8 matches
- Maximum lasts for 16 matches
  *(However, if you are asking for the duration of the actual upgrade I believe it is permanent. After purchasing mine, I depleted my energy and I got to keep the upgrade.)*

**2. Can I buy both?**

- Yes, if you buy Greater first but there's no point to it if you can afford Maximum. After buying Maximum, Greater is disabled.

[image: After purchasing Maximum Reserves]

**3. When buying stamina refills it says "Regain some stamina". How much is "some"?**

- 1 stamina 
  *(in the image below I bought it twice but only captured the second one)*

[image: I purchased 2 "some stamina" but only captured the second one]